# Blank element.style.width property in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I'm testing some templates for pages which will eventually be output by a **HTTP server application**; these pages will mostly be displayed in smart phone browsers, so I'm taking extra pains to achieve a tight layout with scrolling capabilities to handle overflow (to avoid ***wrapping*** which would negatively impact the vertical layout). In one of my preliminary **jsFiddles**, my progress is roadblocked by an anomaly which I can't understand:

Why is the **element.style.width** property returning a ***blank*** value in this fiddle?

https://jsfiddle.net/bkilmer/bcwmozmd/

```
// JavaScript section of Fiddle

//This function returns elements by id
function xid(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

// This function returns debugging string
function EStr(EID) {
var E=xid(EID);
var sep='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
return 'E = ' + E + sep + 'E.id = ' + E.id + sep + 
       'E.style.width = ' + E.style.width; // E.style.width is BLANK
}

// This function syncs the horz position of the header
// with the horz scroll of the associated list
function SyncIndexHeaderScroll() {

  var SLStr = 'scrollLeft='+xid('IndexListDiv').scrollLeft;  
  var IC = xid('IndexContainer'); 
  var IH = xid('IndexHeader'); 
  var ILT = xid('IndexListTable');

  // Sync header position
  xid('IndexHeader').style.left = -xid('IndexListDiv').scrollLeft + 'px';

  // Debug signposting
  xid('AName0').innerHTML = SLStr+'; '+SLStr+'; '+SLStr+'; '+SLStr;
  xid('AName1').innerHTML = EStr(IC.id);
  xid('AName2').innerHTML = EStr(IH.id);
  xid('AName3').innerHTML = EStr(ILT.id);

}

// HTML Section of Fiddle

<div id="IndexContainer">
  <div id="IndexHeader">
    <div id="IndexTimeStampHeader">Time Stamp</div>
    <div id="IndexAlarmNameHeader">Alarm Name / Event</div>
  </div>
  <div id="IndexListDiv" onScroll="SyncIndexHeaderScroll()">
    <table id="IndexListTable">
      <tr>
        <td class="IndexListTimeCol" id="TStamp0">Wed Jan 20 @ 22:23:33</td>
        <td class="IndexListNameCol" id="AName0">Alarm 0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="IndexListTimeCol" id="TStamp1">Wed Jan 20 @ 22:23:43</td>
        <td class="IndexListNameCol" id="AName1">Alarm 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="IndexListTimeCol" id="TStamp2">Wed Jan 20 @ 22:23:53</td>
        <td class="IndexListNameCol" id="AName2">Alarm 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="IndexListTimeCol" id="TStamp3">Wed Jan 20 @ 22:24:03</td>
        <td class="IndexListNameCol" id="AName3">Alarm 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="IndexBottomDiv">
    <button type="button" class="BB" onclick="BackToMenu()">Back To Menu</button>
  </div>
</div>

// CSS Section of Fiddle

#IndexContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FDD;
  border: none;
}

#IndexHeader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #DDD;
  background: linear-gradient(#EEE, #CCC);
  font: bold 12px arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#IndexTimeStampHeader {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 8px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 140px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFF #AAA #AAA #FFF;
}

#IndexAlarmNameHeader {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 8px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 380px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFF #AAA #AAA #FFF;
}

#IndexListDiv {
  background: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
}

#IndexListTable {
  width: 1000px;
}

.IndexListTimeCol {
  width: 140px;
  font: 12px arial, sans-serif;
}

.IndexListNameCol {
  font: 12px arial, sans-serif;
}

#IndexBottomDiv {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 370px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 598px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  background: linear-gradient(#EEE, #CCC);
  font: bold 12px arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #FFF #AAA #AAA #FFF;
}

button.BB {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  font: bold 12px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The first goal of this layout was to create a **column heading** which follows the **horizontal scroll** of the associated list, but remains in a fixed position vertically. This was achieved via the **SyncIndexHeaderScroll** function in the fiddle.

The second goal is to adjust the **IndexHeader.style.width** and the **IndexAlarmNameHeader.style.width** so that they dynamically adjust to the proper **width** to accommodate the horizontal scrolling; however, I can't proceed with this task until I figure out why the **style.width** property is not returning a usable value. There are defaults specified for the referenced widths in the **CSS**, so I'm confused as to why the **DOM/javascript** references do not contain the values specified in the **CSS**.

To debug this anomaly, I've added some code to display the contents of some of the key elements (i.e. **IndexContainer**, **IndexHeader**, and **IndexListTable**) in the second column of the scrolling list; the list will be blank in the finalized template (to be filled in via AJAX queries in the final product).

To see the problem I'm describing, move the horizontal scroll and note that the **bottom 3 debug lines** end with '**E.style.width =** '; I'm expecting to see '**600px**' for the **IndexContainer** and **IndexHeader** elements and '**1000px**' for the **IndexListTable** element (the values specified in the **CSS**).

The **JavaScript Framework** is set to **No-Library (pure JS)** and the **Load Type** is set to **No wrap - in head**. I'd like to keep it this way and ***avoid using JQuery*** (to keep the pages as self-contained and independent as possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `E.style.width`, use `E.offsetWidth`.

Comment: I tried, but it said that I did not have enough reputation points, sorry.

Comment: Oops. It would not let me up-vote it. I didn't realize that I needed to click the check mark. Got it now.